# N-dimensional (linear) interpolation on external table in Modelica

Tags: interpolation, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to extend the functionality provided by Modelica Standard Library's types *ExternalCombiTable1D* and *ExternalCombiTable2D*, to implement an N-dimensional (linear) interpolation (with "N" up to at least 4, possibly getting up to 8) on external data tables (saved on txt data files).
What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna have a look at the current list of ideas for future extensions: https://github.com/modelica/Modelica/issues/1153

Answer (score 1):

Dassault Systems has already implemented this, see https://github.com/modelica/Modelica/issues/1516. If you do not have Dymola, you could ask Torsten Sommer (https://github.com/t-sommer) if he could make it avaible to you.

The support for the SDF-tables ships with Dymola.
Support for Python and ML/SL is available on Github.