# Multidimensional Tables in Modelica Block

Tags: interpolation, modelica, dymola, openmodelica, jmodelica

I started to use openmodelica few days ago. I created a lot of tables where Data is defrost efficiency, first row is Air temperature which is my first input and first column is  Leaving water temperature  from the condenser which is my second input. I created this kind of matrix for five humidity level and for 4 number of compressor so I have 20 matrix.

I would like to create a modelica block with 4 inputs:

- Air temperature
- Leaving water temperature
- number of compressor
- humidity level

and as output the defrost efficiency which is in the tables. Can someone help  me please ?

I can't use the block `CombiTable2dv` which is in open modelica because i have 4 input and 20 tables.
I found [modelon article](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/096/092/ecp14096092.pdf) which speaks about a library but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: The SDF library mentioned by Markus A. is the newest version of the HDF5Table Library you linked in the paper. The library was renamed to SDF in the meantime. There are also Python and Matlab implementations available on https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat

Comment: May you explain how to use NDTable block ? I created a SDF file using Dymola SDF Edtor but i don't manage to use it. Thanks you

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736504/n-dimensional-linear-interpolation-on-external-table-in-modelica

Answer (score 4):

In Dymola there is the (free) SDF library for this purpose. In case you don't have Dymola some information can be found here: [SDF-Paper](https://2014.international.conference.modelica.org/proceedings/html/submissions/ECP14096885_AndresDiehlSommer.pdf). For testing you can download a free demo [here](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/catia/products/dymola/trial-version/) (you need to register).

Comment: May you explain how to use NDTable block ? I created a SDF file using Dymola  SDF Edtor but i don't manage to use it.   Thanks you

Comment: Did you take a look at the example in "SDF.Examples.TabledDiode"? 

Some things to consider: 
(1) nin corresponds to the numbers of scales you attached to the dataset, 
(2) if you already have the file it is easier to leave "readFromFile = true", 
(3) instead of the "loadResource" function you can use an absolute path, 
(4) datasets always start with a "/"

Comment: Thanks you for the help. I managed to use a 3-D Database. Now I would like to use a 4-D Database but I can't create it with Dymola SDF Editor because the max dimension is 3. In your opinion  Should I use groupes to add a dimension,  or try to generate a 4-D Database using Python or something else ?

Comment: I would go for Python. There is a small but useful intro at https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-Python. Manually going beyond 3D isn't very convenient anyway. As an alternative you can use MATLAB as well https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-MATLAB.

Comment: Do you know if dymola can use  unstructured tables indeed i have  a dataframe where the values of a scale change with other parameter. For this reason I guess that I can't create a SDF file and so I can't use *SDF library.   Can you advice me something  ?

Comment: Markus, could you comment on "free"? Is it free as in beer, or free as in speech? The code on github is BSD3, but it seems the C part and the Modelica part is missing. Is that available under an OSI certified license as well?

Comment: Actually my "(free)" was referring to SDF coming with Dymola without additional cost, but as Dymola is coming with costs the whole package is not free. For the C and Modelica part: There is a discussion ongoing on the licensing. But I expect this to take quite some time...

Answer (score 2):

N-dimensional table interpolation is missing in the [Modelica Standard Library](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary) indeed. The developers are aware of the need and discussed it previously, however could not converge towards some data input format for multi-dimensional arrays. What would your requirement (or even proposal) be like?